# How to make Ext.Ajax.request only after form fields are loaded completely

Tags: ajax, extjs

I have a function which uses following code to fetch form values-

```
var formValues = this.myForm.getForm().getValues();
```

MyForm contains a combobox which loads with form. (There are two separate requests for combo load and form load)

As these two requests are loading at the same time, above code do not return combo values as they are still loading.

Is there any way to check whether combo values are loaded and then only send ajax request for form load so that above code will have all form values?

**Edited:**

LoadComboBox function just fills the data with some store.

Following is the code for form load-

```
loadFormGrid: function (){
var allValues = this.myForm.getForm().getValues(); // this do not consider combobox values

Ext.Ajax.request({
      params: {action: 'getList', data : allValues },

      // ... some code
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

On the success event of the combo box load, call the load method of the form/make your ajax request to populate the fields of the form.

**EDIT:**
Here is what I mean:

The place where you instantiate your ComboBox probably looks like:

```
var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
 store : new someStoreType({
           //add to catch the loaded event
           listeners : {
              'load' : function(store, recs, options){
                      loadFormGrid(); 
                  } 
            }
         })
});
```

The store listener above (`'load'`) will catch when the combo box is loaded and will call the function to populate/load the form.

Comment: One update- I cant make changes in combo box load, I can only change form load method

Comment: @ShikhaShah, how do you load the comboBox and the form? Can you create a fiddle with a demonstration of the code? Or perhaps paste some code in your question?

Comment: The solution looks good. But I cant make changes in combo load. I want to check whether all form fields have completed loading before getting form values (I guess I can do it only in loadFormGrid()).

Comment: @ShikhaShag, then you would have to hardcode retrieving the selected value of the comboxbox and checking if it is already loaded. So, combobox.getValue().